# Largest double in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to return the largest double in an array using recursion.

sz is the number of elements in the array.

start is the index of the array that begins the current call.

This is what I have so far. Why doesn't the function terminate when it hits the 'return max' line!?

```
double arrayMax (double arr[], int sz, int start) {
double max;

if (start == sz) {
    return max;
} else {
    if (arr[start] > max) {
        max = arr[start];
    }
    arrayMax(arr, sz, start+1);
}
return max;
```

}

Comment: The function call does terminate when it hits the `return max;` line.

Comment: When it hits return max, it calls arrayMax another few times and then returns the first element in the list instead of the largest double in the list.

Comment: OMG, why would anyone want to use recursion for this? If this is a school homework (sounds like one), then this is not going to teach you how to code, this is going to teach you how NOT to code. Have you heard of stack overflow? You will see one when you try this "algorithm" on a large array. :)

Comment: @stumpylumpy How do you know it calls arrayMax another few times?

Comment: Take a step back and look at what this function does. First, it declares a `double` variable and does not initialize it. Then, either it returns this uninitialized value, or it sets the variable to the first element in the array, calls a function and ignores the result, then returns the value of the variable. So it either returns an uninitialized value, or it returns the first element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
double arrayMax (double arr[], int sz, int start)
{
    double max;
    if(start >= sz - 1)
    {
        max = arr[sz - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        max = arrayMax (arr, sz, start + 1);
        if(arr[start] > max)
        {
            max = arr[start];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

No additional parameter, no helper function...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't have any assigned max value in your second line. Which will cause a problem. Because you are trying to return it if the size and the start integer values are the same - I beleive that is happening when array has only one element in it.

So you are saying that, if my array has only one element, return some value that named max, but nobody knows what is inside of it, the value. (Undefined Behavior)

However, it is also wrong too. Because as you see, we are giving value to max variable, but since we are defining and declaring it in all calls, this leads us to use huge memory. So better way is you need to give your max variable and it's value in your function as a parameter, it is the better way.

Secondly, it would be better for you to return your recursive function. Because you don't have a return in your recursive call. You need to do this in both places.

First, you need to return your max value when all of your function ends, and second you need to return your function to make another recursive call in above stages than end of your function.

This code is the same with ghostman, so I am with him on this one.

```
double arrayMax (double maxValue, double myArray[], int arraySize, int startPoint) 
{
    if (startPoint < arraySize) 
    {
        if (myArray[startPoint] > maxValue)
            maxValue = myArray[startPoint];

        return arrayMax(maxValue, myArray, arraySize, startPoint + 1);
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with the posted code:

1. The recursion logic is flawed. The way your function is implemented, every call to the functions creates a new local variable `max`. The maximum value is not being propagated across recursive calls.
2. `max` is being used without getting initialized. This leads to undefined behavior.
3. You don't have a `return` in the recursive call.

I would suggest implementing the core logic in a helper function.

```
double arrayMaxHelper(double arr[], int sz, int start, int currentMax)
{
   if (start == sz)
   {
      return currentMax;
   }

   if (arr[start] > currentMax)
   {
      currentMax = arr[start];
   }

   return arrayMaxHelper(arr, sz, start+1, currentMax);
}

double arrayMax (double arr[], int sz, int start)
{
   // Call the helper function.
   // The fact that arrayMax is implemented using a recursive
   // helper function is a detail. Callers of the arrayMax()
   // shouldn't have to worry about it.
   return arrayMaxHelper(arr, sz, start, std::numeric_limits<double>::min):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double arrayMax (double max, double arr[], int sz, int start) {

if (start < sz) {

    if (arr[start] > max) {
        max = arr[start];
    }

    return arrayMax(max, arr, sz, start+1);
}

return max;

}
```

If array length is not determined or very large then it's a **very** bad way. Imperative languages work better with iteration algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive call, you increment `start`, but you don’t decrement `sz`. Therefore the to do list of the algorithm does’t ever get shorter.

Comment: `sz` marks the end of the array, which is fix, while `start` moves towards it.